# Firebase: Why does my Code only use the first document in my Collection?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I hope somebody can help me, I am searching for hours. The problem in this code is that in the log file of Firebase there only stands:

> "after for each =undefinedsensor_location_1undefinedundefinedundefined "

so why does it only use the first document (in this case it is location_id which is the first document for each Sensor in the Firestore Database)?

The path is occupation.sensor_n.location_id/reserved_by.........

```
admin.firestore().collection("occupation").get().then((sensors:any) => {
  sensors.forEach((sensor:any) =>{
    console.log("after for each=" + sensor.id + sensor.location_id + sensor.reserved_by + sensor.occupied); //collection_id is working
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sensor` in `forEach()` is a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot). It does have `id` property which seems to be working fine but you need to use `data()` to access the data in document. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
admin.firestore().collection("occupation").get().then((sensors:any) => {
  sensors.forEach((sensor:any) =>{
    const { location_id, reserved_by, occupied } = sensor.data()
    console.log("after for each = ", sensor.id, location_id, reserved_by, occupied); 
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I understand the Problem
Thanks for your3 help, you saved my day ;)

but in the console.log should stand a + ;)

Comment: Have a nice Week my friend

Comment: You're welcome. Using `+` would just concatenate those values (if string) and `,` will log them individually.. with a whitespace in between.